# How to install virtualmin on UBUNTU 20.04 LTS

Tags: virtualmin

I was unable to install virtualmin on UBUNTU 20 LTS but I successfully installed webmin on 20.04 LTS.
Please can anyone help me out to install virtualmin on UBUNTU 20.04 LTS

Your cooperation will be highly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Sarah

Answer (score 0):

```
wget https://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/scripts/install.sh

sudo /bin/sh ./install.sh
```

The script will display a warning message about existing data and compatible operating systems. Press `y` to confirm that you want to continue the installation.

The script will take some time to complete all the steps as it installs various software packages and components.

Once the script completes, you can configure the root password.